# ¿Cómo puedo preparar Sublime Text 2 o 3 para programar en android?

Tags: android, sublimetext

quería saber si hay alguna manera de utilizar Sublime Text para programar en android, a la hora de escribir el código fuente se que si puedo, pero para errores/compilar y tal hay algún plugin o tendré que hacerlo a mano?

El Android Studio se que es realmente bueno, pero mi ordenador de 6GB de RAM se queda corto para que funcione fluido.

Gracias de antemano :D

Comment: Buenas, puedes investigar e instalar algunos paquetes como este : https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Android, sinceramente no lo he usado. Personalmente te recomiendo que programes en Eclipse http://www.aprendeandroid.com/l1/instalacion.htm  y utilices GennyMotion https://www.genymotion.com/  como emulador, lo probé en una maquina con 4 gb de Ram y funcionó a la perfección. Saludos

Comment: Yo en mis inicios utilizaba sublime text para programar en Android, la compilación lo hacia con AIDE dentro del mismo dispositivo, los archivos los tenia sincronizados con github, era nada más guardar esperar 3 segundos, pulsar compilar y en menos de 20 segundos ya estaba corriendo la app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andrew es un ligero proyecto de desarrollo de Android para Sublime Text 2 y 3. Hace uso de Monitor para conseguir un ambiente completamente funcional para el desarrollo de Android, sin la molestia de un IDE grande.

De momento, sólo funciona para las plataformas de base Unix (Linux/Mac OS X).

Puedes obtenerlo desde [GitHub](https://github.com/Korcholis/Andrew)

Requerimientos:

1. Android SDK instalado en tu equipo
2. Si eres usuario linux establecer los [permisos](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/device.html#setting-up) de dispositivos.
3. Tener [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) instalado para compilar las aplicaciones Android.

Antes de empezar debes configurar tu entorno.

1. Dar la ubicacion del SDK desde

> Andrew > Preferences > Locate SDK

2. Seleccionar el espacio de trabajo para los proyectos desde

> Andrew > Preferences > Workspace path

3. Verificar que todo funcione desplegando Android SDK Manager desde

> Andrew > Android managers > Android SDK Manager

4. Iniciar el desarrollo del proyecto desde

> Android > New Android Project

Compilar y enviar al dispositivo

Existe la opción de compilar, depurar o liberar (y si usted tiene un almacén de claves, directamente pueden firmar cualquier release .apk), pero puede también compilar, depurar y enviar al primer dispositivo conectado a la computadora, abrirlo automáticamente cuando se instala.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, tu respuesta no está respondiendo la pregunta, por eso creo que es conveniente dejar comentarios sobre este tema. Saludos

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, la editare.

Comment: Buen trabajo estimado, Saludos